# Get transaction fee after its completed

Tags: ethers.js, etherscan

In my project, I'm using the ethers.js library to interact with the blockchain. After the transaction is completed, I can see on the etherscan what was the fee (please see the attachment). [image]

I'm looking for a way to get this fee value from the ethers.js library. I was looking for such information in the documentation but didn't find anything here: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/transaction/#Transaction.

Is this possible? If not with the ethers.js, then does the etherscan provide any API for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with ethers.js
But seems like you are not using the correct function to get the information about the transaction.

here: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#TransactionReceipt

You can see **gasUsed** and **gasPrice** field and this is the information about the transaction fee.

So `totalFee = gasUsed * gasPrice`

Hope your project success.

Comment: Yeah, this works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NodeJs or ReactJs to call the function you can do the following procedure

```
 try {
      const transaction = await contract.methods
        .function()
        .call({ from: accountAddress });
      
      console.log("tx details:", transaction)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

This will console, whole transaction detail and you can get transaction hash from there

Comment: Don't copy & paste the same answer into multiple questions. If the questions are too similar mark the question as duplicates.

Comment: sure, will take care in future